# CQRS module example magento2

Tags: magento2.3, best-practice, coding-standards

Can anyone point to some decent github repository where module implements CQRS, SOLID, DRY and testing? I was reading about MSI, but it is kind of complex and huge and I am looking for something simpler that implements best practices

Answer (score 0):

that's the point of CQRS if you have something simple you usually no need neither CQRS nor DDD (Domain Driven Design). It makes sense to apply them only for complex business domains